# Getting species from ensembl sequence id

Tags: ensembl, api, orthologues

I have downloaded some orthologues from ensembl website in fasta format. The problem is that it uses the ensembl sequence id as name for the sequences. I want to know the species name or any other information about the sequence (chromosome, location...) For example for this sequence id: ENSMODP00000018933. How can I do that? I have been looking at the REST API but the most I can find is an API call for getting the sequence passing the id as parameter.
https://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/sequence_id
I have also tried this API call but does not work for sequence ids:
https://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/xref_id

Comment: Use efetch for NCBI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [lookup/id endpoint](http://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/lookup) will get it for you. Of you can just look up the three letter species code, in this case MOD, [on the list in the documentation](http://www.ensembl.org/info/genome/stable_ids/index.html).

Comment: I made a script that uses the list in the documentation. The lookup returns me almost always that: {"error":"Expand option only available for Genes and Transcripts"} Thanks.